# question about compact space and closed subset

Tags: general-topology

A ‎subset ‎$‎‎A‎$  ‎of ‎‎space ‎$  ‎(‎‎X‎,\tau)$ ‎has ‎‎$‎\alpha‎$‎-‎property ‎if  ‎every ‎$‎\tau‎$‎-open ‎ ‎‎‎cover of ‎‎$‎A‎$‎ has a finite subfamily whose ‎‎$‎\tau‎$‎‎-closures ‎(resp.‎‎ $‎\tau‎‎_{‎A‎}‎$‎‎-‎closures)‎ ‎cover ‎‎$‎A‎$‎.‎

By definition every compact space has ‎‎$‎\alpha‎$‎-‎property. **Can we say?**

A space that has ‎‎$‎\alpha‎$‎-‎property is compact if only if each closed subset has ‎‎$‎\alpha‎$‎-‎property.

**How can I prove it?**

Answer (score 1):

Both claims are true. For the first claim, this is because if X is a compact space then any open cover of A has a finite sub-cover. Therefore, just take the closure of each element of the sub-cover.

For the second claim, you can dispose of the "A space that has the $\alpha$-property". Indeed, suppose that X is compact. Each closed subset of X is also compact since any closed subset of a compact set is compact, and hence, each closed subset has the $\alpha$-property.

Conversely, suppose that each closed subset of X has the $\alpha$-property. In particular, $X$ has the $\alpha$-property as a closed subset of itself. Let $U_\alpha$ be any open cover of X. Since X is closed, it has a finite subcover of closed sets $V_\alpha$.  However, just take $V_\alpha^c$ to arrive at a finite sub-cover.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. Wkat does "just take $V^c_{\alpha}$" mean?

Comment: Each $V_\alpha$ is closed. Therefore, $V_\alpha^c$, the complement of $V_\alpha$, is open.

Comment: Of course. But what  go you mean by "take"?

Comment: I mean use the $V_\alpha^c$'s as the open cover.